# Right-to-left Styling Shape

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am facing the below issue that when I am changing text direction from ltr to rtl

The triangle shape will be lost

How can I create this shape in rtl direction

Shape before changing the direction  `[1]:https://jsfiddle.net/0a1b5jud/`

Shape after changing the direction to rtl  `[2]:https://jsfiddle.net/x432drps/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
.pricing-table-3 .pricing-table-header {
     right: 0;
     transform: scaleX(-1);
}

h4, 
.pricing-table-3 .pricing-table-header p {
     transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsq5kdey/11/). 
More about `scaleX()` [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX())